# Can't get value on paste event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check pasted text in textbox to validate it but it is always blank.

How can I get text during while user paste it?

```js
function alertandclear(obj) {
console.log('->' + obj.value);
obj.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="setTimeout(alertandclear(this),100)"/>
```

Comment: Can any of 2 downvoters pls explain their action?

Comment: `setTimeout(alertandclear(this))` is not the way to use setTimeout. When you add `()` after function name, it will be called immediately. So setTimeout is passed undefined as callback and does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `setTimeout(alertandclear(this),100)` instead of you should have reference to function in `setTimeout` as below

```js
function alertandclear(obj) {
console.log('->' + obj.value);
obj.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="setTimeout(alertandclear.bind(null,this),100)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function reference or expression inside the `setTimeout`.[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Here is what I did.

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("paste",function(){
          var element = this;
          setTimeout(function(){console.log(element.value);element.value='';},100,element);
   });
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```